# Hamburger menu links aren't working properly

Tags: html, mobile, menu, navigation

I am making a website that should be responsive: on mobile screens, a hamburger menu should appear. It works properly on the homepage (index.html), when I click on a link it scrolls exactly to the section that I want on the same page. So far so good.

But when I navigate to another page of the website (because it has more than a page) and try to navigate through the hamburger menu it becomes weird: When I click on a link from the menu the URL changes automatically to become like the following pattern: NAME_OF_CURRENT_PAGE#SECTION_NAME instead of: INDEX.HTML#SECTION_NAME, because I want that every time a user clicks on a link from the mobile menu (Hamburger menu) it will lead him/her to the dedicated section on the Homepage (index.html).

I should mention that on the desktop version all works fine.

The code :

```html
 <div class="col-12 col-md-10 d-none d-xl-block">
            <nav class="site-navigation position-relative text-right" role="navigation">

              <ul class="site-menu main-menu js-clone-nav mr-auto d-none d-lg-block">
                <li><a class="linka nav-link" href="index.html#home-section">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="linka nav-link" href="index.html#about-section">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="linka nav-link" href="index.html#team-section">Team</a></li>
                <li><a class="linka nav-link" href="index.html#services-section">Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="linka nav-link" href="index.html#partners-section">Partners</a></li>
                <li><a class="linka nav-link" href="index.html#contact-section">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </nav>
          </div>


          <div class="col-6 d-inline-block d-xl-none ml-md-0 py-3" style="position: relative; top: 3px;"><a href="#" class="site-menu-toggle js-menu-toggle text-black float-right"><span class="icon-menu h3"></span></a></div>

        </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please change the `href="index.html#home-section"` to `href="#home-section"` and see if it works?

Comment: Hello, it wouldn't work because the (#home-section) exists only in the "index.html" page.